# How can I parse an attribute with nested arguments with darling?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I'm trying to parse an attribute with [darling](https://docs.rs/darling), and I want to support the following usages:

```
// att not specified
#[derive(MyTrait)]
struct Foo(u64);

// att specified without an argument
#[derive(MyTrait)]
#[myderive(att)]
struct Foo(u64);

// att specified with an argument
#[derive(MyTrait)]
#[myderive(att(value = "String"))]
struct Foo(u64);
```

These are my types:

```
#[derive(FromDeriveInput)]
#[darling(attributes(myderive))]
struct MyDeriveInput {
    #[darling(default)]
    att: Option<MyAttr>,
}

#[derive(FromMeta, Default)]
struct MyAttr {
    #[darling(default)]
    value: Option<Path>,
}
```

And a test:

```
#[test]
fn test() {
    let derive_input = syn::parse_str(
        r#"
        #[derive(MyTrait)]
        #[myderive(att)]
        struct Foo(u64);
    "#,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let parsed: MyDeriveInput = FromDeriveInput::from_derive_input(&derive_input).unwrap();
    assert!(parsed.att.is_some());
}
```

I get this error:

```
thread 'test' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:
Error { kind: UnexpectedFormat("word"), locations: ["att"], span: Some(Span) }'
```

I get the same error if I specify `att`, regardless of whether `value` is specified.

Is this possible? If so, what structure does darling expect to parse this into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for the derive doesn't exactly work this way for attributes values which are structs.

If you want to specify there's an `att` but a default one, you should set it as `att()`.

Here's a fixed complete code and test units:

```rust
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate syn;

use {
    darling::*,
    std::path::*,
};

#[derive(FromMeta)]
struct MyAttr {
    #[darling(default)]
    value: Option<String>, // I dunno what was your "Path" so I've put String
}

#[derive(FromDeriveInput, Default)]
#[darling(attributes(myderive))]
struct MyTrait {
    #[darling(default)]
    att: Option<MyAttr>,
}


#[test]
fn test() {

    // with specified MyAttr:
    let derive_input = syn::parse_str(
        r#"
        #[derive(MyTrait)]
        #[myderive(att(value = "test"))]
        struct Foo(u64);
    "#,
    )
    .unwrap();
    let parsed: MyTrait = FromDeriveInput::from_derive_input(&derive_input).unwrap();
    assert!(parsed.att.is_some());

    // with default MyAttr:
    let derive_input = syn::parse_str(
        r#"
        #[derive(MyTrait)]
        #[myderive(att())]
        struct Foo(u64);
    "#,
    )
    .unwrap();
    let parsed: MyTrait = FromDeriveInput::from_derive_input(&derive_input).unwrap();
    assert!(parsed.att.is_some());

    // with no MyAttr:
    let derive_input = syn::parse_str(
        r#"
        #[derive(MyTrait)]
        #[myderive()]
        struct Foo(u64);
    "#,
    )
    .unwrap();
    let parsed: MyTrait = FromDeriveInput::from_derive_input(&derive_input).unwrap();
    assert!(parsed.att.is_none());


    // with no myderive
    let derive_input = syn::parse_str(
        r#"
        #[derive(MyTrait)]
        struct Foo(u64);
    "#,
    )
    .unwrap();
    let parsed: MyTrait = FromDeriveInput::from_derive_input(&derive_input).unwrap();
    assert!(parsed.att.is_none());
}
```

Comment: It' a bit disappointing if it's necessary to include `()` even if there are no arguments :/

Comment: It's hard to define a consistent and obvious spec here. The behavior for bool is a little special, especially if you consider the default value of a bool is false.

Comment: @PeterHall Why not create an issue on darling's GH repo? They may have a workaround

Comment: @DenysSéguret there is indeed a workaround, but it's not easy to find right now. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68637124/86381)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this, using [`darling::util::Override`](https://docs.rs/darling/0.13.0/darling/util/enum.Override.html). I've never had a great name for this particular utility, so I'm going to add this exact snippet as an example, and am interested in having a discussion on GH for a name that people are more likely to find.

Comment: The language in the docs is may have caused some confusion too. I took "inherit" to refer to the struct that you are parsing into, something like struct-level attributes being inherited at the field-level, or that kind of thing. So it didn't seem relevant to my problem.

Comment: Yeah, the name `inherit` comes from where this type was originally used, in the `#[builder(default)]` attribute. Like serde, you can say `#[builder(default = "...")]`or just `#[builder(default)]`. The latter case means "IF the struct has a default, via the `Default` trait or an expression, inherit from that ELSE use `Default` on the type of this field."